# Getting org/springframework/dao/QueryTimeoutException after upgrading to Spring 4 and hibernate 4.3.5

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I recently upgraded by SPRING + Hibernate project to Spring 4.1.6 and Hibernate to Hibernate 4.3.5 .But doing so I am getting this exception

```
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [fileName]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/QueryTimeoutException
```

This is the POM file with Hibernated dependencies and I am using PostgreSQL as database

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
  </dependency> 

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
  </dependency>
```

This is the configuration in fileName

```
<bean id = "transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <tx:attributes>
                    <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
                    <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
            </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
```

Any help to resolve this problem will be truly appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error,

```
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [fileName]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/QueryTimeoutException
```

it is clear that the container is not able to load the class file `QueryTimeoutException`.

The file comes with [`spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx/4.1.6.RELEASE)

add this dependency

```
           <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
              <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
           </dependency>
```